# iPad not all screen recognising touches

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, touches

So my current app project is a camera based app and all is going well so far but I have run in to a weird little issue and don't know if there's something basic i'm missing or if it's something more complex.

When I run my app on the iPad in landscape mode (right hand home button), the right end of the screen doesn't recognise touch down events, though if an item is spread across the border (half recognising touches, half not) and you press on the good half and drag, it still recognises the touch and also recognises the touch up event when you let go. Through testing, I worked out that it works fine up to pixel 768 so this makes me think that one of the views thinks that the application is still running in portrait. But then when I run it in portrait, the bottom section (same portion) doesn't work either.

I have looked at another couple of posts on SO:

[Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533878/ipad-landscape-only-app-not-responding-to-touches-near-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

[Article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281385/ipad-landscape-trouble-detecting-touches-on-lefthand-portion-of-screen)

I have tried the fixes they say, but have had no luck as of yet. It may be something to do with the fact I have various different views created both programatically and in the interface builder and somewhere along the way, something isn't being initialised correctly but I have tried changing them all, I may have missed some though.

If anybody can shed any light on my situation, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Add mine to the list, heh. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792641/uitableview-portion-loses-interaction-after-device-rotation All of mine were created programatically though... still have not yet found a solution or new way of thinking to try to fix the issue.

Comment: I agree with @dasdom that setting the backgrounds would help you a lot. Try this first.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has something to do with autoresizing mask. Have you set this? Try to set the background color of all views to see where they are.